# C++ decltype evaluate wrong type

Tags: c++

I have the function which type the same as minimal argument:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B>
auto Min(A a, B b) -> decltype(a < b ? a : b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
 
int main()
{
    auto b = Min(5, 2.0f); // float
    auto a = Min(5, 6.0f); // also float ?!
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

But actuale I've got float for a and b. And my console print looks like:
float
float

Why the second function return type evaluating also as float ?

Comment: Why do you think there should be a difference ? You pass the same types (int + float) in both calls.

Comment: The return type is not dynamically evaluated. It is the resulting type of the expression of `decltype`. Also `auto` will give you a static type. You can work with `std::variant<A, B>`, if you really want to do that.

Comment: Ternary operator must always have single return type from both branches. Your attempt with `decltype` cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional operator (`?:`) can only yield a single type.  In your case, `int` and `float` share the common type `float`, so that is the type the expression will yield.

If you don't want that, you'll need to move your code from being executed at run time and move it into being executed at compile time.  Doing that allows you to return different types depending on the conditions at compile time.  That would give you a `min` function like:

```
template<auto a, auto b> auto min()
{
    if constexpr(a < b) 
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

In the above code, if the `if constexpr` is false, the whole `return a;` is discarded and the entire body of the function become `return b;` and if it is true, the opposite happens and your left with just `return a;`.  This allows the function to return the type and value of the minimum object.

making this change to your code will give you

```
#include <iostream>

template<auto a, auto b> auto min()
{
    if constexpr(a < b) 
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
 
int main()
{
    auto b = min<5, 2.0f>(); // float
    auto a = min<5, 6.0f>(); // int
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

which ouputs

```
i
f
```

as seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4f1d80fad0f7f21)